# Deserialize a Blob longer than 6000000?

Tags: apex, blob

is there a way in Apex to store data in a Blob without using JSON, for example by casting?  JSON has a limit when deserializing of 6MB, and our data is sometimes more than that.

The problem is that storing data as JSON within an attachment as a serialzied JOSN is possible, even if the size exceeds 6 MB, but that deserializing the same data gives the error:

> String length exceeds maximum: 6000000

Is it possible to store the data - without serializing it - as a blob, and then directly casting the blob back to the data format it was originally in.

Comment: Did you try the toString() method on the blob - `[blob].toString()`"Casts the Blob into a String" although not sure what that would do to heap on a 6MB string

Comment: Please read [x-y problem](http://xyproblem.info/). It sounds like you've got a more fundamental problem you need solving, and this problem might not be the one you need to solve.

Comment: The problem is that storing data as JSON within an attachment as a serialzied JOSN is possible, even if the size exceeds 6 MB, but that deserializing the same data gives the error "String length exceeds maximum: 6000000".  So I was asking if it is possible to store the data - without serializing it - as a  blob, and then directly casting the blob back to the data format it was originally in.

Comment: Is there a reason you don't store the data inside the json as a normal record?  How are you planning to use the json data? If possible could you describe the json data you're working with a little more? (6 mb of json is quite a bit, is there binary data there?)

Comment: @hamayoun, are you asking whether there's a way to go from Apex objects or sObjects directly to and from a binary blob, without JSON as an intermediate format? If so, the general-case answer is no, but giving more details about the problem may reveal other solutions.